# I am getting the LatLng points but the polyline is not showing on the map

Tags: java, android

I am getting the LatLng values and I am placing all those latlngs into arraylist(points), when I debugged the code I can see that latlng points are entering into the arraylist ,but I am not getting the polyline on the map. Thank You in advance.

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null ) {
            points=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            Lat=bundle.getDouble("latitude", 0d);
            Lng=bundle.getDouble("longitude", 0d);
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+Lat+","+Lng,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()‌​;
            point = new LatLng(Lat,Lng);
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            polylineOptions.width(8);
            points.add(point);
            polylineOptions.addAll(points);
            googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: will you change polylineOptions.addAll(points); with for loop and try ?     for(int i=0;i<points.size();i++){
                        polylineOptions.add(points.get(i));
                    }

Comment: try this sample http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/07/draw-polyline-in-google-map-version-2.html

Comment: I guess you are executing this code in a loop where you are adding point in points ArrayList, so julst move last two line out of your loop and you will get all your polylines drawn in your map. the last two line ` polylineOptions.addAll(points);
            googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);`

Comment: @Clairvoyant - I placed those two line outside the loop, but then also i did not get the polyline.

Comment: @RagamaiK - can you post your full code to help you in right way instead of guessing and answering you.

Comment: @Clairvoyant - here is my code, I am getting the intermediate latlng from the service which i have written in my project. I am getting those LatLng and i can see those in toast also.

Comment: private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getExtras() != null ) {
points=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
Lat=bundle.getDouble("latitude", 0d);
Lng=bundle.getDouble("longitude", 0d);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+Lat+","+Lng,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
point = new LatLng(Lat,Lng);
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
polylineOptions.width(8);
points.add(point);
polylineOptions.addAll(points);
googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
}
}
};

Answer (score 0):

Don,t recreate arraylist while calling broadcast receiver.
May this help you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  ArrayList<LatLng> points=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
 private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getExtras() != null ) {

        Lat=bundle.getDouble("latitude", 0d);
        Lng=bundle.getDouble("longitude", 0d);
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+Lat+","+Lng,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()‌​;
        point = new LatLng(Lat,Lng);
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
        polylineOptions.width(8);
        points.add(point);
        polylineOptions.addAll(points);
        googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
    }
  }
 };
}
```